# how to add two elements with tailwind?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I intend to add two elements with tailwind on top of each other.
What I did was the following.

```
<div class = "w-10 h-10" id="container">
  <button class = "relative w-4 h-4 bg-red"> Iniciado </button>
  <button class = "absolute top-16 left-28 w-4 h-4 bg-red"> item </button>
<div>
```

The result is:

[image]

But if I add more items to my container it starts moving my item element like this:

[image]

Is there a way for those 2 elements to stay fixed and not move if I add more elements to my container?

Comment: Can you give code snippet of the second output, by adding new element what do you actually mean

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are supposed to position the absolute element relative to the main container

```html
<div class="relative w-10 h-10" id="container">
  <button class="w-4 h-4 bg-red"> Iniciado </button>
  <button class="absolute top-16 left-28 w-4 h-4 bg-red"> item </button>
<div>
```

Here is a workaround.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/4AGwU2QuBQ

I hope it help.